# Route for custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

What is the route for the url: http://localhost:3000/images/10/thumb/200x300 ? Where 200 is width for the image and 300 is height for the image

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [url params](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) instead.

This is how you use it:

http://localhost:3000/images/10/thumb?width=200&height=300

Than you can use it in your code:

> params[:width]